# What is the recommended home design software?

Tags: basement, tools, software, drafting

I am going to be finishing my basement.  I would like to design the new basement myself using design software.  What is the recommended home design software?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/820/affordable-2d-drafting-software-for-amateurs) question. [Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/#utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-google&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=google%20SketchUp) seems to be a good option if you don't want to pay big bucks.

Also, here's a [tutorial](http://www.finehomebuilding.com/item/12812/use-sketchup-to-create-a-3d-framing-model) for framing layout in Sketchup.

Comment: When I first tried Sketchup I struggled. But then I saw what other people were doing with it and I watched and walked through training videos. I'm so glad I did because I can draw things freely now. I cannot recommend this highly enough. It is an AWESOME bit of software. I liked the tutorials on this website: http://sketchupforwoodworkers.com/ They're geared toward the sort of designs I wanted to do.

Answer (score 3):

Good roundup of tools from here: http://www.charlesandhudson.com/archives/2010/07/3d_virtual_room_planning_tools.htm

A couple that stand out, both run in your browser, and allow drag-and-drop of furniture and appliances, measurements on walls, 3D renderings, etc.

- [Autodesk Homestyler](http://homestyler.com/designer)
- [MyDeco 3D](http://us.mydeco.com/rooms/austin/)

Answer (score 1):

I used 3D Home Architect several years ago. It worked well and was inexpensive. As a matter of fact, I got it to design my basement.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article ([in Swedish](http://www.byggahus.se/artiklar/valja-ritprogram/)) comparing 28 different programs for drawing houses. The summary table is straight forward even if you do not speak Swedish, and [translated via google](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=sv&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.byggahus.se%2Fartiklar%2Fvalja-ritprogram) probably is ok quality to get the points made.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Home Designer Suite](http://www.homedesignersoftware.com/products/home-designer-suite/) by [Home Designer Software](http://www.homedesignersoftware.com/), the consumer version of the [Chief Architect](http://www.chiefarchitect.com/) professional 3D home design software. [Here is a version of a house](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwLiD.jpg) that I created. It is not free, but for ~$99 I really like the functionality and features.