# Looking for alternatives to AutoCad to make floorplans and interior elevations for my kitchen

Tags: software, planning

I am looking to remodel my kitchen. I want to start with floorplans and inside elevations of the 4 walls, cabinets, and major appliances. I've been using [LibreCAD](http://www.librecad.org/) because it supports Autocad 2000 format (dxf) and is free and open source.

I've been struggling with LibreCAD, so I want to know what is the best Open source or web based app out there for a non-architect to make 2D floorplans and elevations, and save them in dfx format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Affordable 2D drafting software for amateurs?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/820/affordable-2d-drafting-software-for-amateurs)

Comment: Google sketchup. Free and easy.

Comment: Sketchup is fantastic. Watch a few video tutorials and make plenty of use of your middle mouse button/scrolly. It makes using the tool 3x faster.

Comment: @user2492: Last I checked the free version of sketchup does not export to dxf.  If you know enough about the format, you can easily write a plug-in that would allow dxf export.

Comment: Do you mean 'DXF'? Personally, I think OSS is great, but I don't blame the OS world for not caring much about DXF...it has a history and AutoDesk hasn't been completely open about the file format.

Comment: Why do you need DXF? What are you doing with the DXF files?

Comment: Alex, I want to be able to export to DXF so I can feel confidant that the files could be opened 20 years later. DA01, LibreCad and FreeCad support DFX, and I don't know of a better interchange format for CAD. I mean if there was a SVG extension that allowed you to specify dimension lines, and absolute sizes that most CAD apps supported I'd use that.

Comment: Future-proofing is a laudable (and challenging!) goal. See below.

Comment: I'm not sure Autodesk, themselves, have plans to allow you to open their own files 20 years form now in AutoCad. ;)

Answer (score 10):

I personally use [Google SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/) to model both the interior and exterior of our house.  It may not have the depth of features you're looking for but if you're going for <strike>open source</strike> freeware that's pretty usable out of the gate you can't go wrong.

As a side note, I have seen some people use [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) to do modeling, though more for in-home manufacturing.

Comment: SketchUp is a truly great program, but FYI, it's not Open Source. It's freeware, but the source code is wholly owned by Google.

Comment: @DA01 Nor is it web based, but it's not clear why the original poster specified either of those things. Perhaps he meant "freely usable"?

Answer (score 4):

SketchUp Pro allows direct export to DXF.

Sketchup (free) allows you to export DAE, which can be converted via FBX to DXF. See, e.g.:
http://www.cadforum.cz/cadforum_en/qaID.asp?tip=6416

Answer (score 1):

I have tried CatStd http://www.cadstd.com/ some. It works OK, but I'm not well versed in it. It does save in dxf format. When I did my basement, I used an older version of 3D Home Architect. It was extremely easy to use, but I don't remember if it saved in dxf format.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to second recommendations for Google Sketchup, with this additional note for those who point out that some features are limited to the paid "pro" version.

If you are a student or faculty, you can obtain the pro version for free until the following July. They seem to be quite liberal in their interpretation of "student or faculty;" it apparently doesn't have to be an accredited university.

Our small farm cooperative teaches two-week intensive Permaculture Design Certificate courses, and submitting the syllabus was enough for them to grant us an educational license.

But you have to renew the ed license every July.

In addition to the lack of .DXF support, the other "biggie" is that you cannot create dynamic components. That should not be a big issue for most people, but it is fun to make doors that open when you click on them, etc. which you can only do in the pro version. But literally 95% of the functionality of Pro is in the free version, including the ability to *use* dynamic components created in the Pro version.